# Creating a numpy array in Python containing cosines

Tags: multidimensional-array, numpy, python-2.7

I'm trying to create an n x m numpy array populated by a set of cosines like cos(v_t), cos(2 * v_t), cos(3 * v_t), ..., which I've tried to do with the following;

```
v_t = np.linspace(0,tmax,tsteps)
m_psi = np.zeros([tsteps,m])
for i in xrange(m):
  for j in xrange(tsteps):
    m_psi[j,i] = np.cos(v_t * k * 2 * pi/T)
    k += 1
```

but this returns the error

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I need every element of the array to be one of these cosines, rather than a row or a column of the array being a cosine (because I'm going to perform some kind of operation like np.dot(R,m_psi), where R is another 2D array, and the result of this multiplication must also be a matrix).

EDIT: To clarify, I'm looking for something like

```
[[cos(v_t),     cos(2*v_t),   ...,cos(m*v_t)],
[cos((m+1)*v_t),cos((m+2)*v_t,...,cos(2*m*t)],
[etc.]]
```

Comment: I want k to vary from 1 to m*steps, but that's easy to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Based on you comment below, this non-working code:

```
v_t = np.linspace(0, tmax, tsteps)
m_psi = np.array([tsteps,m])
for j in range(m):
    m_psi[:,np.cos(v_t*m*2*pi/T)]
```

Could be translated into working numpy as:

```
v_t = np.linspace(0, tmax, tsteps)
m_psi = np.empty((tsteps, m))
for j in xrange(m) :
    m_psi[:, m] = np.cos(v_t * m * 2 * np.pi / T)
```

You can achieve the exact same thing in a more elegant and numpythonic way using broadcasting instead of a loop :

```
v_t = np.linspace(0, tmax, tsteps)
m_psi = np.cos(v_t[:, None] * np.arange(m)[None, :] * 2 * np.pi / T)
```

---

You´ll have to figure out some of the details, but something like this may be what you are after:

```
v_t = np.linspace(0, m * tmax, m * tsteps)
m_psi = np.cos(v_t * 2 * np.pi / T).reshape(tsteps, m)
```

If we leave the cosine part out:

```
>>> m = 4
>>> tsteps = 5
>>> np.arange(m * tsteps).reshape(tsteps, m)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

and the values in these array would be what multiply the base value inside your cosine in the code above.

Comment: This seems to reshape the cos(v_t) array.

Comment: @DanielBlay It does reshape the `cos(v_t)` array, but starting from a longer `v_t` array to achieve what I think you are  after. If it isn't I'd suggest you rewrite your question giving the mathematical expression of `m_psi[i, j]`, because we are having a hard time figuring what you are after.

Comment: I've edited the question a little. I'm sorry that I'm finding it hard to clarify - I've been coding for all of 3 weeks, and my supervisor has asked me to write a program along these lines, but his example code didn't work. All I really know is that I'm trying to do something with a continuous signal (sum of cosines), and part of the process involves multiplying the signal vector by a random matrix R and the matrix psi, which is the cosine basis matrix (i.e. matrix with elements cos(t) to cos(nt)).

Comment: The code he provided me with is;
    v_t = np.linspace(0, tmax, tsteps) \n
    m_psi=np.array([tsteps,m]) \n
    for j in range(m): \n
      m_psi[:,np.cos(v_t*m*2*pi/T] \n

Comment: Well, this certainly works in that it doesn't return an error. I don't think it's what my supervisor wanted (he said the matrix should be orthonormal, which this is not), but clearly I don't know what he wants either, so I think this is as close to an answer as I can get.